# Name for a submitted form

Tags: word-request

At work I'm dealing with software for creating and managing web forms.

Multiple users on the web can submit forms. Now each submission needs to be processed, it can be modified, acted upon, deleted etc.

For example, for an online survey each submission needs to be evaluated statistically. For a contact form, each submission requires an answer.

I am looking for a term how to call each submission. For certain forms, it can be called "answers" (survey), "questions" (contact form), "orders" (shop) etc.

I am looking for a general (possibly technical, but understandable by an average user) term for a submitted form.

Currently the term "form record" is being used, but I'm not certain if that is a common term.

Sample sentences:

- This XXX cannot be deleted.
- Change the status of an XXX to "in-progress"/"rejected"/"archived" etc.
- The inbox contains each XXX.
- Export an XXX as an XML file.
- Attach a file to an XXX.

I have been thinking about "submission", but it does not really fit the last sentence above.

Comment: If it helps, the German term used is "Vorgang".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible answer is in the question itself. The best word I could suggest is:

> **submission**

Besides the obvious meaning : The process of submitting something, when you want to address something that you have received from someone and you want to use a generalized term for the same, you could use _"submission".

Look at Definition 2b. of the word '[Submission](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/submission)':

> something submitted; a proposal, argument, etc

Let us try using them in the sentences you provided:

> - This submission cannot be deleted.
> - Change the status of the submission to "in-progress"/"rejected"/"archived" etc.
> - The inbox contains each submission.
> - Export a submission as an XML file.
> - Attach a file to the submission.